# How to identify xpath of an element which do not have any attribute information

Tags: javascript, xpath

I want to identify an element which is a text "My Portal" from `td` tag. Below is my HTML

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- rendered always true, custom column names are also label -->
            My Portal 
            <!-- rendered always false, this feature is not required -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have tried below `xpath`s as shown below, but none of them works:

```
1. .//td[text()="My Portal"]
2. .//td[contains(text(),"My Portal")]
```

After some search in the internet I found `normalize-space()` method which will remove the trailing and unnecessary white spaces. I have tried the method using the below xpath

```
.//td[normalize-space()="My Portal"]
```

Am able to identify the element, but in the firebug it is showing as 2 matching nodes. Please find the attachment for the highlighted elements in the firebug[image]
My questions are:

1. Why two tags are getting highlighted?
2. Why `.//td[contains(text(),"My Portal")]` does not work?
3. How to identify the "My Portal" uniquely?

Can anyone please help?

Comment: 1st question is easy - if you look at the structure, the text content, removing all html, of both TD's would be the same

Comment: @JaromandaX, can you please let me know how to identify the same uniquely

Comment: you got two answers in the last 4 hours - I couldn't answer all 3, hence a comment not an answer :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions. An efficient approach is to specify the exact path from the root node to the `td` you want. Something like

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[normalize-space()='My Portal']
```

If you know that there are no more than two nesting tables, you can shorten this to

```
//td//td[normalize-space()='My Portal']
```

If you want the `td` in the innermost table regardless of table structure, try

```
//td[not(.//table) and normalize-space()='My Portal']
```

This isn't very efficient though. If you know that the text "My Portal" appears in an immediate text child of `td`, try

```
//td[text()[normalize-space()='My Portal']]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The second approach worked perfectly fine. Can you please explain me about `not(.//table)` more.

Answer (score 1):

To uniquely identify the second td, what you have to do is add an additional filter. So if you look at the difference between the 2 tags highlighted, the parent has a class and the child doesn't. So if you need the second td, the xpath would be //td[normalize-space()='My Portal' and not(@class='rich-table-cell')]

If you need the parent then:  //td[normalize-space()='My Portal' and @class='rich-table-cell']

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `text()` try `.`

```
.//td[contains(.,"My Portal")]
```

Comment: I have tried the `xpath` you suggested, but 4 matching nodes are getting displayed. It is highlighting the complete hierarchy which contains `td` tag

Answer (score 0):

To Answer your questions:

1- Because you are using a global selector, "//", with this selector XPAth will find all the elements into the tree, so if you want select only one td you should specific the path, something like this

```
/table/tbody/table/td[contains(text(),"My Portal")]
```

2- The command that you are using it should work, I already tried, check your path again, maybe you are not selecting his parent or you are starting from the wrong path.

```js
function xpath(){
  
  var input = document.getElementById("xpath").value
  var cell = document.evaluate( input, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
  var cellvalue = cell.iterateNext();
  console.log(cellvalue);
  alert(cellvalue.data);
  
};
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
  <body>
<input type="text" id="xpath" value='//body/table/tbody/tr/td/table//td[contains(text(),"My Value")]/text()'/> <input type="button" onclick="xpath()" value="Execute"/>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <table>
        <tbody>  
          <tr>
            <td>
            My Value
              </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I have tried the `xpath` given in the answer for the first question. It is still not working.